# Sping Boot http/2 server sends GOAWAY after 20 seconds

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat, http2

I wrote a simple HTTP/2 server using **Spring Boot** (*version 3.0.5, Java 17, Tomcat 10.1.7*). I can see that the server sends *GOAWAY* to the client exactly after *20 seconds* of the connection setup. Is this parameter configurable? Can I disable the the GOAWAY frame altogether?

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution. Set

```
server.tomcat.keepAliveTimeout=-1
```

in the `application.properties` of your Spring Boot preject. -1 signifies no timeout.

[Reference](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/config/http.html)